# How to mock Navigator.push result in an onchange callback

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito

I have this widget inside a Page :

```
FormSelectedWidget(
  onChanged: () async {
    Location? result = await Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      RouteName.searchLocationScreen,
    ) as Location?;

    if (result != null) {
      context.read<MyActionCubit>().updateForm();
    }
  }
)
```

how do i verify updateForm() is called once ?

```
verify(
  () => MyActionCubit.updateForm(),
).called(1);
```

is there any way to mock `Location? result` using mocktail ?